# SharpSVN: SvnDepth.Exclude throwing exception

Tags: .net, updates, depth, sharpsvn

Below is some code to exclude a folder from a working copy (an ancestor folder).  "r" is showing an System.InvalidOperationException when I break on that line.  Does Exclude work?  What is my alternative to this option when using the SharpSVN .NET library.  I haven't had any issues with Exclude for any of the other Depth types.

```
            SvnUpdateArgs updateArgs2 = new SvnUpdateArgs();
            updateArgs2.Depth = SvnDepth.Exclude;
            SvnUpdateResult r = null;
            client.Update(path, updateArgs2, out r);
            string x = r.ToString();
```

`r.GetType().GenericParemeterAttributes` **= " 'r.GetType().GenericParameterAttributes' threw an exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' "**

`r.GetType().GenericParemeterAttributes.base` **= "Method may only be called on a Type for which Type.IsGenericParameter is true".**

I'm not sure which Type it's referring to.

===========

## Edit:

This worked!

```
SvnUpdateArgs updateArgs2 = new SvnUpdateArgs();
                updateArgs2.Depth = SvnDepth.Exclude;
                updateArgs2.KeepDepth = true;
                SvnUpdateResult r = null;
                client.Update(path, updateArgs2, out r);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To look at your specific exception I would really need a stack trace, not just some out of context error.

To exclude a path, you should set .KeepDepth on the SvnUpdateArgs to true.

Without .KeepDepth your code is equivalent to

```
$ svn up --depth exclude PATH
```

which would yield an error.

With with .KeepDepth it would be the

```
$ svn up --set-depth exclude PATH
```

that you try to apply.

In SharpSvn it is easier to use the slightly more low level

```
SvnClient.CropWorkingCopy(PATH, SvnDepth.Excluded)
```

as that makes it clearer what you try to do.

Comment: when I use this code, I get this error: "You can only crop a node to a depth between empty and files.  Parameter name: toDepth ... Actual value was Exclude."

Comment: adding "KeepDepth = true" worked for the original code!  Thank you very much!!

Comment: do you know where I can download the actual source code for SharpSVN?  What site is the source of that library?

Comment: You can checkout the source from svn at https://ctf.open.collab.net/svn/repos/sharpsvn. Or you can use the PDB file to just step through the compiled source if you enable sourceserver support in your Visual Studio.